# Using generic bounded wildcards when testing Maps with junit

Tags: java, generics, junit, hamcrest

I'm trying to understand why this junit assertion is giving me a compile time error:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> actual = methodToTest();
assertThat(result, hasEntry("foo", new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("bar"))));
```

If I write it this way it works fine:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> actual = methodToTest();
Set<String> expected = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("bar"));
assertThat(result, hasEntry("foo", expected));
```

The compiler error from the first example is:

```
The method assertThat(T, Matcher<? super T>) in the type Assert is not
applicable for the arguments (Map<String,Set<String>>, Matcher<Map<?
extends String,? extends HashSet<String>>>)
```

`HashSet<String>` is a subtype of `Set<String>` so why isn't this working?

Comment: does it work in java8?

Comment: Not sure this was attempted in java 7.

Comment: ["wildcard hell"](http://bayou.io/draft/Capturing_Wildcards.html#Wildcard_Hell) :) just cast away the problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HashSet<String>` is a subtype of `Set<String>` true.

However, `Matcher<Map<String,HashSet<String>>>` is **not** a subset of `Matcher<Map<String,Set<String>>>`. Remember that a `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`.

The `assertThat` method expects an argument of type `Matcher<? super Map<String, Set<String>>>` which is incompatibe with `Matcher<Map<String,HashSet<String>>>`.